# Expression Tree Cast to ICollection<T> & Add

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I need to create an Action that will very efficiently and repeatedly:

1. Cast an object-type variable to an ICollection-type variable
2. Cast an object-type variable to a T-type variable
3. Add the T-type item to the ICollection-type collection.

It's my understanding that building an expression tree and storing the action for reuse is the fastest way to do this.  I'm having a lot of trouble with that.  To make this a little more clear, I need an expression-tree-compiled-action that will do this:

```
private void AddToCollection(Type itemType, object item, object collection)
{
    // assume itemType is used in the expression-tree to cast to ICollection<T>
    ((ICollection<T>)collection).Add((T)item);
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a generic function?  What does using expressions give you?

Comment: It's not possible with the `Type itemType` argument. The only possible is to create `Action<object, object>` for a specific `Type` and then calling it multiple times passing `object item, object collection`. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Amy I can't use a generic method because I don't have a type argument.  I already derived the instance of the collection using reflection from a property marked with an attribute.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes that would work.  I could cache a new action for each type that I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to create *efficiently* non reflection code which does

```
private void AddToCollection(Type itemType, object item, object collection)
{
    // Assume that itemType became T somehow
    ((ICollection<T>)collection).Add((T)item);
}
```

because in order to avoid the reflection, the `Type` has to be known in advance (either concrete or generic type argument).

What is possible though is to create something like this:

```
static Action<object, object> CreateAddToCollectionAction(Type itemType)
{
    // Assume that itemType became T somehow
    return (item, collection) => ((ICollection<T>)collection).Add((T)item);
}
```

Here is how:

```
static Action<object, object> CreateAddToCollectionAction(Type itemType)
{
    var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "item");
    var collection = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "collection");
    var body = Expression.Call(
        Expression.Convert(collection, typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(itemType)),
        "Add",
        Type.EmptyTypes,
        Expression.Convert(item, itemType)
    );
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(body, item, collection);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var add = CreateAddToCollectionAction(typeof(int));
object items = new List<int>();
add(1, items);
add(2, items);
```